# Animate (slide down) time change in a timer

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a timer, it updates every 1s using setInterval.

I want to animate seconds to slide down or up everytime it updates.. same to minutes and hours.

My function looks somewhat like this:

```
var RenderTime = setInterval(function(){
    function(){
        return hour + minute + second;
};};1);
```

The code I have is a bit different than the example in here, and it works great. My problem is that I want to add the animate to slide down time change.

Update:
An example of what I want to achieve (in terms of animation, not style):
http://ro31337.github.io/jQuery-Countdown-Timer/

[image: jQuery countdown timer]

Comment: What exactly do you want to slide down? Can you give some more examples?

Comment: As I have explained, I want to slide down the second as they change.

Comment: https://www.templaza.com/Forum/attachment/1704/thumb 
You can see here, when the 5 slides down, 6 follows, then 6 slides down and 7 replaces it....

Comment: I updated my answer to include a live example

Comment: Look at your Live-Example page. There is a github link. You can edit this script easily to show hours too.

Comment: If I wanted to use a plugin, I would have done that. I am trying to use vanilla js, as you can see the tags to my question to include jQuery or any other plugin.  I am trying to look at these plugins and understand their approach though

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

**CSS animations or Javascript?**

With CSS you can animate most any property you like. Just add a class to the number you want animated.

```
@keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: -200px;}
}
.animate-move {
    animation: mymove 1s;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Javascript animations are more performance heavy, but better supported than CSS animations.

```
// Example in jQuery
$(".number").animate({
    top: -200,
}, 1000);
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

**What CSS property are you animating?**

There are 3 main ways:

1. `position:absolute` and `top` properties.
2. Negative `margin` property (your example)
3. `transform` property (`transform: translateY(-200)`)

**Example using CSS animation**

https://jsfiddle.net/tj8nrrcf/

Comment: My question is intended beyond the basics, I know how to use CSS or jQuery to animate. But I want to know how to access the second, and animate it after I rendered the HTML. Inside setInterval I used innerHTML to render time every second as it updates.. I want to know how to display that time in a way I can animate each block of digits.
Thank you

Comment: If you're using CSS animations, it's just a matter of applying a class in your innerHTML, no? https://jsfiddle.net/tj8nrrcf/

Comment: We can animate and control it when we have the element that is coming next.
Take this as an example, and tell me which approach we can take to animate the seconds http://codepen.io/programking/pen/Jyxri

Comment: You can use the approach in the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/tj8nrrcf) I provided. You just need to set the innerHTML to two elements instead of a static number text node.